# Build Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a Markers google maps array which looks like this.

```
markers: [{
    position: {
        lat: 37.0636782,
        lng: -8.0288746
    },
    infoText: 'Marker 1'
}],
```

I also have content I have pulled from my CMS which looks like this.

```
[{
    "latitude": "37.0636782", 
    "longitude": "-8.0288746", 
    "info_snippet": "test123"
},
{
    "latitude": "37.0636789", 
    "longitude": "-8.0288745", 
    "info_snippet": "test111"
}]
```

I want to take the second array and output it the same as the first array. Is this possible?

As requested here is the loop I created.

```
this.pins = response.data.acf.map_markers;
let self = this;
this.pins.forEach(function(item) {
    self.markers.position.lat.push(item.latitude);
    self.markers.position.lng.push(item.longitude);
    self.markers.infoText.push(item.info_snippet);
})
```

Comment: Sorry. No need to downvote. Here is my attempt posted below the Array.

Comment: One call to `Array.prototype.map` solves it

Answer (score 1):

Map through your original and create your custom keys there. In your case it would be something like this:

```
this.pins = response.data.acf.map_markers;

this.pins.map(({latitude, longitude, info_snippet}) => ({
  position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
  infoText: info_snippet
}));
```

```js
const coords = [{
    "latitude": "37.0636782",
    "longitude": "-8.0288746",
    "info_snippet": "test123"
  },
  {
    "latitude": "37.0636789",
    "longitude": "-8.0288745",
    "info_snippet": "test111"
  }
];

const newCoords = coords.map(({latitude, longitude, info_snippet}) => ({
  position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
  infoText: info_snippet
}));

console.log(newCoords);
```

Comment: I would like to loop through "coords" to make these values dynamic. How difficult would that be?

Comment: I'm confused. With `map()` you essentially are looping through `coords`.